# When saving a DOCX Word document in PDF, the document takes over an extra page (I need 15 pages sharp and in pdf it becomes 15 pages and 9 lines)

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2010

When saving a DOCX Word document in PDF, the document takes over an extra page (I need 15 pages sharp for online submission and in pdf it becomes 15 pages and 9 lines). I save from word by printing the document using Bullzip PDF printer. Why are the extra lines created?

Comment: Do you have blank lines at the end of the document? Which is your Windows version?

Comment: Also, is the output format A4 or letter? A4 is slightly bigger then letter and may account for the difference.

Comment: Is **Bullzip PDF printer** the default printer?  If not, try setting it as the default printer.  Go in your DOCX and check formatting.  Sometimes software formatting and printer formatting are different.

Comment: See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TextReflow.htm